# How to create global Motion Blur parameters and control them globally?

Tags: python, nuke

I'd like to create a global parameters in The Foundry Nuke UI to control a motion blur value and shutter's angle.

How to accomplish this by using Python?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Could you tell me what OS you're using NUKE in?

Comment: i'm in mac os X sierra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found quite simple and effective method to globally control `MotionBlur` in Nuke – just using usual `NoOp` node, serving as controller, and ***LinkerScript***. Here's how it works in practice. Create, for testing, three `Transform` nodes (every Transform node contains `motionblur`, `shutter` and `shutter offset` knobs).

Run the ***LinkerScript*** internally in NUKE's Script Editor or externally via `menu.py` file. Then select all the `Transform` nodes and from NUKE's toolbar choose: `Gizmos` – `NoOp Controls Linker`. That's all. Now you can globally control `MotionBlur` for all the `Transform` nodes via `NoOp` controller (`motionblur` and `shutter` properties are now linked through expressions).

Here's my ***LinkerScript***:

```
import nuke

controller = nuke.nodes.NoOp() 
# There are two identical parameters in parentheses : 
# the 1st one is a real property's name, and the 2nd one is a label for GUI.
knobMB = nuke.Double_Knob('motionblur', 'motionblur')
knobSH = nuke.Double_Knob('shutter', 'shutter')
controller.addKnob(knobMB)
controller.addKnob(knobSH)

def linkNoOpControls():
    for everyNode in nuke.selectedNodes():
        everyNode['motionblur'].setExpression('NoOp1.motionblur')
        everyNode['shutter'].setExpression('NoOp1.shutter')

toolbar = nuke.menu("Nodes")
gizmos = toolbar.addMenu("Gizmos", icon='LinkerIcon.png')
gizmos.addCommand("NoOp Controls Linker", 'linkNoOpControls()')
```

You should load a `24x24 pixels` PNG icon file for your new command in the toolbar.

[image]
[image]

P.S. Don't forget to drop your PNG icon file into a hidden `.nuke` directory (if you use a Mac, as you said, its path is – **`/Users/<userName>/.nuke`**), and adjust your **`menu.py`** file accordingly (paste the necessary Python code).

For more details read a [Nuke Directory Locations](https://support.foundry.com/hc/en-us/articles/207271649-Q100048-Nuke-Directory-Locations) article.